# Is it possible to use goto with switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, goto

It seems it's possible with C#, but I need that with C++ and preferably cross platform.

Basically, I have a switch that sorts stuff on single criteria, and falls back to default processing on everything else.

Say:

```
switch(color)
{
case GREEN:
case RED:
case BLUE:
    Paint();
    break;
case YELLOW:
    if(AlsoHasCriteriaX)
        Paint();
    else
        goto default;
    break;
default:
    Print("Ugly color, no paint.")
    break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  I think it might be possible...

Comment: Why not use standard programming practice and have the `else` and the `default` call a function (inline or otherwise) as they are intended to perform the same action.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham you cannot use goto default; default is a keyword and cannot be used as a label.  the fact that C# is doing it is screwy :-) hehe ...

Comment: It would actually make as much sense to have default as just another label that is the default if non match.  That is what the assembly does.  If the value isn't in the jump table it will jump to the default location.

So I would not say that allowing one to jump to default: is screwy.  The screwy part is that some languages treat switch like an if/else-if with booleans.

Comment: Beached 1) i was talking about parse phase of C; C keywords are NOT allowed to be used as labels; 2) you are presuming that the generated assembly WILL use a label/jump ... What if the target CPU uses some completely different branching mechanism?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not quite but you can do this:

```
switch(color)
{
case GREEN:
case RED:
case BLUE:
     Paint();
     break;
case YELLOW:
     if(AlsoHasCriteriaX) {
         Paint();
         break; /* notice break here */
     }
default:
     Print("Ugly color, no paint.")
     break;
}
```

OR you could do this:

```
switch(color)
{
case GREEN:
case RED:
case BLUE:
     Paint();
     break;
case YELLOW:
     if(AlsoHasCriteriaX) {
         Paint();
         break; /* notice break here */
     }
     goto explicit_label;

case FUCHSIA:
     PokeEyesOut();
     break;

default:
explicit_label:
     Print("Ugly color, no paint.")
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 48):

Ahmed's answer is good, but there's also:

```
switch(color)
case YELLOW:
    if(AlsoHasCriteriaX)
case GREEN:
case RED:
case BLUE:
        Paint();
    else
default:
        Print("Ugly color, no paint.");
```

people tend to forget how powerful switches are

Comment: @Matt "Many people (even bwk?) have said that the worst feature of C is that switches
don't break automatically before each case label.  This code forms some sort of
argument in that debate, but I'm not sure whether it's for or against."

Comment: It's not about the lack of breaking, it's about putting case labels in between the components of an if-block.

Comment: I'm wondering, if `color` is `BLUE` and `AlsoHasCriteriaX` is `false`, would that call both `Paint()` and `Print()`? Or: how is the `else` statement evaluated if you jump right into the `if` body?

Comment: Automatic breaks in C would introduce a level of complexity that's not desired in C.  C is supposed to be very very close to the machine.   If you put automatic breaks then you introduce implicit local jumps in the code which is something that C avoids, everything in C strives to explicitlybe mapped to Assemblers.

Comment: @AhmedMasud well brian kernighan, and tom duff think it's a lot less black and white.

Comment: The real problem with this code is when you try to change/add something.

Comment: Forget all the criticism. This snippet is awesome and real programmers must be able to cope with this kind of things. Thumbs (and vote) up!

Comment: points for creativity, but I hope to not encounter this outside an academic exercise :}

Comment: @LShadow77 if you swap if for a while you basically have a duff's device