# How can I call switch case 4 from case 5?

Tags: c++

I have a switch statement:

```
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
//some compute
break;
case 2:
//some compute
break;
case 3:
//some compute
break;
case 4:
//some compute
break;
case 5:
//Call case 3
//Call case 4
//perform my own function
break;
}
```

How do I call the function of case 3 and case 4 then perform my own computation at case 5.

The only way I could do is to run the same code of case 3 and then case 4 then my own computation, I wonder is there a way to call case 3 & 4 directly like calling a function then return back to case 5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202199/is-it-possible-to-use-goto-with-switch

Comment: Done. place them in a function and resolve every issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly do that. You could put the case code in a function and then call that function though.

```
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
//some compute
break;
case 2:
//some compute
break;
case 3:
doCase3stuff();
break;
case 4:
doCase4stuff();
break;
case 5:
doCase3stuff();
doCase4stuff();
//perform my own function
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in functions/methods and invoke them in the corresponding cases.

Comment: if i place them in a function, it will say some variable not declared etc as those variable are declare in main , what should i do

Comment: @baokychen Are your variables used to share/exchange information between your functions? if so you should use a class to pack your data and the corresponding functions.

Comment: @baokychen declare these variables in the function? Pass them as parameter? Define them as static? Define them as global? It depends on what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that you could place it into a loop, and in case 5, change choice to 4. 
Or, if it's possible you could perform a recursive call, passing 4 as the choice instead of 5.

Comment: That would be overly complicated and horrible to read code though.

Answer (score 1):

Then make case 3 and case 4 code as two functions so you can call it there with no duplicate code writing, otherwise you can only achieve that by goto which is not a good idea