# How do if/else work intermixed with switch/case interact?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, duffs-device

In a question about switch and goto, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125146/8340131) used this code to avoid using a goto altogether:

```
switch(color)
case YELLOW:
    if(AlsoHasCriteriaX)
case GREEN:
case RED:
case BLUE:
        Paint();
    else
default:
        Print("Ugly color, no paint.");
```

How does this code work? I understand that cases automatically fall through, so I don't need it explained when `color` is `YELLOW`, but what about when `color` is `GREEN`? How does C++ handle `else` when it never encountered `if`. Would this code even compile, would it be a runtime error, or would it just ignore the `else`?

Comment: "Would this code even compile," - why not compile it and find out?

Comment: Look at [Duff's_device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: This is evil. I love it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192246/switch-case-weird-scoping